# Problem serving firebaseui.css in VueJS from node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, vue.js, vue-cli

So basically I've got this problem for a long time now and thought I fixed it but that wasn't the case.

I started the development of my site with [this guide](https://blog.sicara.com/a-progressive-web-application-with-vue-js-webpack-material-design-part-1-c243e2e6e402) and it helped me create a PWA using the vue-cli.

While adding firebase authentication to it I also used [this guide](https://medium.com/dailyjs/authenticating-a-vue-js-application-with-firebase-ui-8870a3a5cff8) to add firebaseui to my project.

It told me to add this line to my index.html

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css" />
```

sadly this didn't worked out and I got this error message in my chrome console:

```
Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'
 because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

This was 2 months ago and I tried a lot of things to fix this issue before finding a temporary solution:

When following the link to the CSS resource I got a "Cannot GET /node_modules/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css" in my browser and I thought that maybe my local server wasn't serving this file.

So I went into the build/dev-server.js file and added this line:

```
app.use(express.static('node_modules'))
```

and changed the link in my index.html to:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css" />
```

Now my website correctly loads all firebaseui components when running "npm run dev" but now it still doesn't do it when running "npm run build" as my server prints this:

```
"GET /firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css" Error (404): "Not found"
```

I guess this makes sense, as I am writing this down because I previously only changed the code in the dev-server.js and not in a build/production related file

Basically, I am asking for a way to user the firebaseui.css without having to change stuff in the dev-server.js to have it work in production or for someone to tell what other files in the build directory I have to edit to make it work.

Thanks in advance and if you need to see more of my code pls ask for it and I will update this post!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Holy shit, so I did more generic digging and found this discussion:

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/604

fixed my issue by deleting both the import in the index.html and the now useless app.use line in dev-server.js

and now I simply added

```
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css'
```

in my main.js and the firebaseui components are rendering properly on both the dev and production build! :)

Comment: I was having an issue in React where when I loaded the StyledFirebaseAuth it caused the font/spacing to change very slightly on my page (I assume because a new one was imported?).  I added this line to my App.js and now it stays consistent.  Thanks!